# write unicode characters into a file in php

Tags: php

I have a json array which is holding the correct string independent of language but when the json is encoded and wrriten into the file it doesnot have the correct values. Its has the the other value random english alphabets eg:(uuadb) I want to write a  string into a file  where the string could be in any language.Now i am testing with tamil language. But i found PHP doesn't support unicode. please help me how to write unicode charaters into the file using PHP.
I tried using pack function but how to use the pack function for any languages Or is there any other way of doing this.Please help me......

Comment: What do you mean it "does not have the correct values"?  Could you post the incorrect values versus what you expect?

Comment: PHP can work with Unicode just fine. You just have to be careful to use the mb_*() functions to deal with the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're seeing `\uXXXX` escapes instead of the non-ASCII characters you asked for.  [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) appears to always escape Unicode characters:

```
<?php
$arr = array("♫");
$json = json_encode($arr);
echo "$json\n";
    # Prints ["\u266b"]

$str = '["♫"]';
$array = json_decode($str);
echo "{$array[0]}\n";
    # Prints ♫
?>
```

If this is what you're getting, it's not wrong.  You just have to ensure it's being decoded properly on the receiving end.

Another possibility is that the string you're passing is not in UTF-8.  According to the documentation for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), these functions only work with UTF-8 data.  Call [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on your input string, and make sure it outputs either `UTF-8` or `ASCII`.